# Включить в pipe поиск строки из *.txt по част. совпадению и выдать объединенный полный результат

Tags: linux, списки

Генератор выдает в конвейер данные:

```
generator | tee -a ~/result.txt
```

и выдает результат построчно в виде `XXX_ZZZ` на сохранение. Имеется другой текстовый документ `~/text.txt`, в котором строки вида `XXX-YYY` (при этом XXX без дубликатов все разные).

Как включить в конвейер процесс поиска по сгенеренным `XXX` и частичному совпадению их из `~/text.txt` и выдать объединенный полный результат вида `XXX-YYY_ZZZ` на сохранение в `~/result.txt`?

Comment: *sed* умеет брать данные из второго файла. Спецификатор *r* смотрите.

Comment: можно было бы воспользоваться программой join, но ей требуются отсортированные строки. а чтобы отсортировать, надо получить весь список строк. ваш генератор выдаёт конечный набор строк?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin из вопроса действительно неочевидно, должен ли сохранится порядок в выводе.

Comment: `text.txt`может быть сортированный. Я не знаю, нужна ли тут сортировка, так как все значения и `XXX` и `YYY` и `ZZZ` строго уникальны, нужно всего лишь чтобы при выдаче генератором определенного `XXX_ZZZ` обратившись к документу `text.txt`, найти там точно такой же `XXX` (там такой один), с которым в одной строке находится ему соответствующий `YYY` (тоже уникальный) и уже вот эту строку `XXX-YYY` добавить к сгенерированному `XXX_ZZZ` и выдать в конечный документ `result.txt` полную строку `XXX-YYY_ZZZ`.  Результат `result.txt` не сортирован и его сортировка мне не нужна.

Comment: `join` вероятно подойдет, но как это вписать в трубу? По сути, не имеет большого значения, в какой последовательности группы  символы между собой `XXX YYY ZZZ` будут выдаваться к конечном результате, главное, чтобы вписать их в результат в одну строку. Генератор выдает конечные данные, то есть никаких последующих действий не будет, нужно лишь добавить соответствующее значение `YYY` из `text.txt`

Comment: `программа | sort | join - файл2`. ну и разделители придётся привести к общему виду (потом можно и обратно заменить)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin работает, но еще есть проблемы, не до конца разобрался - иногда не выводит результат... может быть какое-то ограничение join по длине строки на вывод? - порядка 150-160 символов в конечной строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно воспользоваться [программой *join*](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html) из набора программ [*gnu/coreutils*](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html):

```
$ join файл1 файл2
```

файлы должны быть отсортированы. при необходимости это можно сделать «на лету» — программа отлично работает с подстановкой процессов, осуществляемой оболочкой. вместо любого из файлов (или обоих сразу) можно указать:

```
<(команда аргументы)
```

также вместо одного из файлов можно указать `-` — данные будут браться из *stdin*:

```
$ программа аргументы | join - файл2
```

ещё один важный момент: разделитель полей в обоих файлах должны быть один и тот же. указать разделитель можно опцией `-t разделитель`, изменить разделитель в одном (или обоих) файле можно с помощью вышеупомянутой подстановки процесса, сделав подмену, например, с помощью программы *sed*.

---

конкретно в изложенном случае, когда в качестве первого файла используется вывод некоего генератора, который выдаёт неотсортированный список строк с разделителем `_`, а второй файл тоже неотсортирован и имеет разделитель `-`, можно применить сразу всё предложенное выше:

```
$ генератор | sort | join -t _ - <(sed 's/-/_/' файл2 | sort)
```

Comment: Предложенное решение работает, спасибо. Но могут быть заморочки связанные с сортировками текстов. Сортировка должна быть выполнена по общему полю. В хелпе join рекомендуется сортировка `sort -k 1b,1` . Так же, могут быть заморочки с сортировкой из-за `locale`, возможно порой пригодится сортировка `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1b,1` (предварительно импортировав локаль LC_ALL=C)

Comment: 1. объединение же вам требуется по первым полям, потому никаких доп. манипуляций с номерами полей при сортировке не требуется. 2. достаточно, чтобы локаль для сортировки и объединения была одной и той же, а выбор её повлияет лишь на порядок строк в результате объединения, поэтому, если порядок строк в результате не имеет значения, не имеют смысла и манипуляции с локалью.

Comment: если всё-таки будете изменять локаль, то сделать это надо либо перед выполнением команды, экспртировав нужную переменную окружения, либо для каждой программы отдельно (потому что они выполняются отдельными процессами). примерно так: `| LC_ALL=... sort | LC_ALL=... join <(... | LC_ALL=... sort) ...`